# How can I add the same array together in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Here is the code i got.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file name"));
    ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    ArrayList<Date> timeList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    ArrayList<String> consumptionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat dateInWeekday = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yy");

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

        //read the line
        String currentLine = scanner.nextLine(); 
        String[] tokens = currentLine.split(",");

        //string of each value
        String date = tokens [0];
        String time = tokens [1];
        String consumption = tokens [2];

        //convert Str time to date format
        Date timeDateFormat = sdf.parse(time);
        timeList.add(timeDateFormat);
        consumptionList.add(consumption);
        dateList.add(dateInWeekday.parse(date));
    }

    scanner.close();



    double dayTotal = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++){

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dateList.get(i));
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if ((dayOfWeek == 1) || (dayOfWeek == 7)){

            dayTotal +=  Double.parseDouble(consumptionList.get(i));
            count ++;
            }       
    }
}
```

}

So, I want the result to be, for example: 
1/10/14 342 Kwh
1/11/14 292 Kwh
My data is the consumption every 15 mins, so I want the total consumption for that everyday

Comment: What you have tried till now? post some code so that other can help you.

Comment: Is that one array? Because it looks like multiple arrays. Post some code, because it's hard to understand what you need.

Comment: This, lad, is not an array.

Comment: Please add sample data contain in file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<SomeType, Integer>` with `SomeType` being the type of `a`, `b`, and `c`, of course. Then loop over your array (which doesn't look like one from your example btw, but nevermind) and add the counts.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new map that has as key the letter and as value the cummulated sum. You can then iterate over all your arrays, look if the key in the map already exists and add the value of the array to the previous sum of the value of the map.
This will give you a map with the sum of all the different array values.

Answer (score -1):

```
//assign the arrays as
a=(4,5,53);b=(1,55,6); c=(1,2);
double SumA=0;
double SumB=0;
double SumC=0;
//Then find the sum of elements in each array. 
//To get the sum of elements in each array use the for loop
 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
     SumA = SumA + a.get(i);}
 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
     SumB = SumB + b.get(i);}
 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
     SumC = SumC + c.get(i);}

//The generate the final results as
[a,SumA] [b,SumB] [c,SumC]
```